# Strange order that comment flags are handled in

Tags: support, comments, flags, comment-flags

So here's a screenshot of my flags page:

[image]

That seems a rather strange ordering of comment flags being handled…

Why does this happen? Why are comment flags handled first on posts where I've flagged multiple comments?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Flags are sorted in the moderator flag queue by lots of factors, and we basically work top-to-bottom. The time when you raised a flag is just one factor. How many flags have been raised on a post or its comments may also play a role; I don't know the exact algorithm.

Also, we may come across a comment flag while handling other flags raised on a post, rather than while looking at comment flags in particular.

So, yes, the order can look pretty random. It doesn't mean you're doing anything wrong. In fact, there's really nothing you can do about it. You have a solid flagging history, so I wouldn't worry about the order in which the flags are resolved.